# How to reapply .css file after UpdatePanel asynchronous call completed

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, updatepanel, jquery-chosen

I have a nested gridview that is within an UpdatePanel control. After I select row editing, I need create controls in a couple of the columns to chosen dropdown lists.  I need to reapply the chosen plugin AND .css file.  I cannot find a resource that will work.
This is the javascript function call to add the chosen dropdown list:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(onEndRequest);  function onEndRequest(sender, args) {
    if (sender._postBackSettings.panelsToUpdate != null) {
       $.load
        $.getScript("~/Scripts/chosen.jquery.min.js");
        $.getScript("~/Scripts/chosen.jquery.js");
        //This append function is not working.
        $('head').append('<link href="~/Styles/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />');
        (".chosen-single").chosen({
            search_contains: true,
            width: "200px",
            no_results_text: "Sorry, no match!"
        });
    }
};
```

With this `append` function, I am still getting the error of:
.chosen-single not a function.

I am using ASP.NET MasterPages so the `head` in on the Site.Master page.  Maybe the problem is that I need to specify where the `head` is?

Thanks.

Comment: You're missing a `$` before `(".chosen-single")`

Comment: Thank you.  I feel stupid. :)  That got it to run but I am getting an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be enough:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(onEndRequest); 

function onEndRequest(sender, args) {
    if (sender._postBackSettings.panelsToUpdate != null) {
        $("select:not(.chosen-single, .no-chosen)").chosen({
            search_contains: true,
            width: "200px",
            no_results_text: "Sorry, no match!"
        });
    }
};
```

You don't need to load CSS and JS files again given that you load the files before.

Comment: I removed the `.getScript` functions and `append` function and the dropdowns are still not changing to the 'chosen' style of dropdown.  I have this code outside my `document.ready` function.

Comment: Use a breakpoint to verify that `$(".chosen-single").chosen({` line is really called.

Comment: The `.chosen' function does get called.  (There are 3 chosen dropdowns)  The second time it is called I get the error **TypeError: this.form_field.options is undefined**

Comment: Yeah, it looks this this issue https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/2004. Basically, you apply the plugin several times on the same HTML element

Comment: Why do you have the selector `$(".chosen-single")` like this? It should be something like `$('select:not(.chosen-select)')`.

Comment: `.chosen-single` is the class name of the dropdown.

Comment: Yes, but that's not how Chosen is typically initialized. (https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) I guess you need to initialize newly added `<select>` elements and you need to adjust the selector accordingly.

Comment: The `chosen' function works fine throughout my application without any issue.  I have to re-apply the plugin after the UpdatePanel has completed its asynchronous callback.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94975/discussion-between-martin-vseticka-and-gloria-santin).